# JavaScriptCore in Swift Playgrounds

Tags: ios, swift, swift-playground

I'm currently working on a Swift Playground which should run on my iPad. It is using JavaScriptCore which should be available regarding Apple:

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Xcode/Conceptual/swift_playgrounds_doc_format/AvailableSDKs.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40017343-CH5-SW2

Does anyone know how I can import and use it? My iPad always says that it can't find the module. I'm using the latest iOS version 10.3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that some libraries are not available in the playground version for iPad, the link that you shared shows the documentation for swift playground for XCode. Like you, I tried to use JavaScriptCore on the iPad but just like HomeKit and other libraries, it isn't available, finally remember that playground for iPad is designed to learn in a easy and fun way how to program, it's not for professional development, hopefully that this will change soon, after all it has a great potential.

Comment: Even if this is not the answer I was looking for it seems that you are right :)